# displaying a sphere with longitude and latitude grid android

Tags: android, algorithm, grid, geometry, latitude-longitude

I'm developing a AR app in android what i want it to do is overlay a camera image with a section of a grid. this gird should display longitude and latitude.

so this sphere will have a radius of that of the eath plus 12km. and should be such that if you point straight up you will see you current longitude and latitude. I want the lines to be seperated by 10 degrees. meaning i should have 36 longitude lines and 36 latitude lines. I would prefer to keep all code in spherical coordinates with units of radians to save on rounding errors. 
I'm mainly looking for the algorithm to do this as I would like to port this to any camera phone with GPS tracking (Psuedo code more than acceptable).

If I've missed a thread with this already then please point me to it.

Any way I can work out what part of the sphere you can see and display this my problem is just with the building the grid in the first place.

Comment: In spherical coordinates, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system, your latitude lines will have constant radius, constant inclination, azimuth 0 to 360 degrees.  Longitude lines will have constant radius, constant azimuth, inclination 0 to 360 degrees.

Comment: my thought is you would never really see the grid unless you were in few places where the lines are.  see this map: http://www.enchantedlearning.com/usa/activity/latlong/ .  notice that this map has 5 deg (not 10 deg) increments in lat and that there would be no lines over most of the north-east.